# How to include subsets of overlays at different places

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a "graphical" table of contents for my presentation, which I develop and explain using several overlays. Later in the talk I want to refer to it again. For this, I need to "invoke" the ToC slice, but without all the introductory overlays.

**MWE:** I want the overlays 1-3 of the following slide to appear on the beginning of the talk, then some other slides, then overlay 4, then some other slides, then overlay 5.

[image: animated result of the MWE code]

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{standaloneframe}{Contents}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (5,0) {overlay: \overlaynumber};
            \node (a) at (0,0) {A};
            \node (b) at (1,0) {B};
            \node (c) at (2,0) {C};
            \pause % -------------------------------------
            \draw [->] (a) -- (b);
            \draw [->] (b) -- (c);
            \pause %--------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \node at (0.5,1) {some explanation};
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (a.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (a.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (b.south west) rectangle (c.north east);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\againframe<>{}` you can choose which overlay you want to repeat.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}<1-3>[label=foo]{Contents}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (5,0) {overlay: \overlaynumber};
            \node (a) at (0,0) {A};
            \node (b) at (1,0) {B};
            \node (c) at (2,0) {C};
            \pause % -------------------------------------
            \draw [->] (a) -- (b);
            \draw [->] (b) -- (c);
            \pause %--------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \node at (0.5,1) {some explanation};
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (a.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (a.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (b.south west) rectangle (c.north east);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        other frame
    \end{frame}

    \againframe<4>{foo}

    \begin{frame}
        yet other frame
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: animated result of code]

---

With an up-to-date version of beamer this can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}<1-3>[label=foo]{Contents}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (5,0) {overlay: \insertoverlaynumber};
            \node (a) at (0,0) {A};
            \node (b) at (1,0) {B};
            \node (c) at (2,0) {C};
            \pause % -------------------------------------
            \draw [->] (a) -- (b);
            \draw [->] (b) -- (c);
            \pause %--------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \node at (0.5,1) {some explanation};
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (a.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (a.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
            }
            % --------------------------------------------
            \visible<+>{
                \draw [red] 
                    (b.south west) rectangle (c.north east);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        other frame
    \end{frame}

    \againframe<4>{foo}

    \begin{frame}
        yet other frame
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for! I allowed myself to (propose to) slightly edit your answer by adding `\begin{frame}<1-3>`, to completely match it to my question